# What is the purpose of an abrader in flint knapping?

Tags: lapidary, knapping

I'm trying to learn flint knapping, and I keep seeing references to abrading the edge while working the material.

What is the purpose of doing this?  How do I know when an edge should be abraded, and how do I know when I have abraded it sufficiently to go back to pressure flaking?

Comment: @Willeke -- I was sort of torn about your edit, but it includes a partial answer (abrading is done "to strengthen the [edge] in preparation for flake removal") and I think it would be better added as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose is to prepare a flake for improved manipulation.

Abrasion is a process also referred to as '*raking*':

> Raking is the action of carefully dragging a course abrader or other device **to remove "micro" flakes from the edge of a biface or preform** to change it's [sic] shape or give support to an edge before actual abrading is done prior to percussion or pressure work.
>   <sup>[source](https://www.flintknappingtools.com/terms.html)</sup>
>
> Edges being worked [especially while soft hammer knapping] must be ground dull prior to flake removal. **This dulling helps prevent edge collapse**. A piece of sandstone, very soft limestone, or other soft rock may be used to dull the edge.
>   <sup>[source](https://archaeology.uiowa.edu/flintknapping-0)</sup>
>
> The process [of lithic reduction] also involves frequent preparation of the edge **to form better platforms for pressing off flakes**. This is usually accomplished with abraiders made from a coarse-grained stone such as basalt or quartzite.
>   <sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithic_reduction)</sup>

Essentially, the abrasion allows for the force to be distributed more evenly and controllably.